# Elasticsearch get unique values from a text value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have k8s log data collected from fluentbit and sent to elasticsearch with the format such as

```json
{"log": "job_id: 1", "kubernetes.host":"minikube", ... }, 
{"log": "job_id: 2", "kubernetes.host":"minikube", ... }
{"log": "job_id: 3", "kubernetes.host":"minikube", ... }
{"log": "job_id: 1", "kubernetes.host":"minikube", ... }
```

and I would like to write a elasticsearch get query such that it returns unique job_ids as

```json
["1", "2", "3"]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) ,to return the list of unique job ids

```json
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "unique-job-id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "log.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The search response will be

```json
"aggregations": {
        "unique-job-id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "job_id: 1",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "job_id: 2",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "job_id: 3",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Would there be any way to parse the value of "log"? Data I have looks like {"log": "job_id: 1, msg: this job was finished"} so i'm looking for ways to seperate only the job_id

Comment: @pandawithcat there is no direct way to extract only the job id. If you want to achieve this, then you need to modify the way you are storing the data OR you can extract only the job_id from the keys of aggregation response, from the application side.